# Access deined for some users on a site collection

Tags: access-denied

I have a site collection other than the main site in SharePoint 2013. Some of the users cannot access this site despite they have contribute permission. My user id defined in the site collection administration and it cant access . The log error file says : **Application error when access /_layouts/15/AccessDenied.aspx, Error=Exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' was thrown**.

I make sure the site is using Claim Based Authentication.

I was trying to make sure it uses claim, and I did some script in the PowerShell. Unfortunately, the site setting from the site action disappeared from the site>

Kindly help ASAP

Thanks in advanced .

Comment: You need to delete and readd those users since you converted the site to claims based authentication.

Comment: @jpollar I did that before and still not working. The site setting disappeared from the site action. how can I get it back ? . Note that, users are defined as following   i:0#.w|domain\username

Comment: hope someone can answer me :(

Comment: Do you remember what script you ran in PowerShell?

Comment: I did solve that issue of site setting long time back. but still many users cannot access the site. I added myself as a site collection admn and still cannot access it from my PC. I can only access it from the server. Kindly help me :) @jpollar